# Change Height of Div After Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

PROBLEM: 
I have a dynamic form that is using JQuery steps to make it a wizard.  Right now, there is a step where a drop down box selection triggers an AJAX call that then adds form fields to the form.  I need the height of the div that this field is in to become longer based off of the amount of fields added.

IMAGES: 
The form starts with two drop downs: 
[image: Form Before Selection]
Once something is selected for the second dropdown, the AJAX call is made and the form appends fields. 
[image: Form After Selection]

The grey box should resize to accomodate the appended fields.

CODE: 
The CSS for the div is as follows:

```
.wizard > .content
{
    background: #eee;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0.5em;
    min-height: 35em;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I can add a permanent height here, but it's not dynamic.

The form is a Zend Form, so the HTML is as follows:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
<?php if ($this->error) : ?>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <?php echo $this->error; ?>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>

<h3>Details</h3>
<section>
    <?php echo FormElementFactory::create($this, ProjectForm::KEY_PROJECT_NAME, false, true); ?>
    <?php echo FormElementFactory::create($this, ProjectForm::KEY_PROJECT_DUE_DTTM, !($this->uberAdmin)); ?>
    <?php echo FormElementFactory::create($this, ProjectForm::KEY_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION); ?>
</section>
<h3>Options</h3>
<section>
    <?php echo FormElementFactory::create($this, ProjectForm::KEY_REVIEW_PROJECT); ?>
    <?php echo FormElementFactory::create($this, ProjectForm::KEY_WTL_PROJECT); ?>
    <?php echo FormElementFactory::create($this, ProjectForm::KEY_JOB_TABLE); ?>
</section>
<h3>Project Configuration</h3>
<section>
    <?php echo FormElementFactory::create($this, ProjectForm::KEY_PROJECT_TYPES, !($this->uberAdmin), true); ?>
    <?php echo FormElementFactory::create($this, ProjectForm::KEY_PROJECT_SUBTYPES, !($this->uberAdmin)); ?>  
    <?php 
    echo $this->partial('project/project/dynamicFormElements.phtml', array('form' => $this->projectForm, 'div' => 'project-config-elts'));
    ?>
</section>

<h3>Workflow Configuration</h3>
<section>
    <?php echo FormElementFactory::create($this, ProjectForm::KEY_WORKFLOW_TYPES, !($this->uberAdmin)); ?>  
    <?php echo FormElementFactory::create($this, ProjectForm::KEY_WORKFLOW_SUBTYPES, !($this->uberAdmin), true); ?>
    <?php echo FormElementFactory::create($this, ProjectForm::KEY_PROJECT_WORKFLOW_CONFIG, !($this->uberAdmin)); ?>
</section>
```

This generates HTML with the structure below: 
[image: Code Structure]

The highlighted div is the div in question.

My AJAX call is done here:

```
    // Handle AJAX dynamic form creation results
    function updateProjectForm(resp) {
        $('div#project-config-elts').html(resp.html);
    }

    // Handle ajax error
    function projectFormError(req, status, err) {
        var errorString = '<div class="row-fluid alert alert-error">' +
            'Error retrieving project form.' +
            '</div>';
        $('div#project-config-elts').html(errorString);
    }

    // AJAX request to get dynamic Project config form
    function requestProjConfigForm() {
        var request = {project_type: $('select[name=project_types]').val(),
                project_subtype: $('select[name=project_subtypes]').val()
        };

         var ajaxOptions = {
            url: 'projectform',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: updateProjectForm,
            error: projectFormError,
            data: request
        };

        // Initiate the request!
        $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    }

    $('select[name=project_types]').change(function(){
        updateProjectSubtypes(); 
    }); 

    // Handle a change in the selection of the particular project
    $('select[name=project_subtypes]').change(function(){
        requestProjConfigForm();
    }); 

    $('select[name=workflow_types]').change(function(){
        updateWorkflowSubtypes(); 
    }); 

    $.validator.addMethod("validJSON", function(val, el) {
        try {
            JSON.parse(val);
            return true;
        } catch(e) {
            return false;
        }
    }, "*Not valid JSON");

    form.validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $( element )
                .closest( "form" )
                    .find( "label[for='" + element.attr( "id" ) + "']" )
                        .append( error );
        },
        rules: {
            project_config: { validJSON: true }
        }
    });
```

I'm thinking that here I can dynamically change the height, but I'm not quite sure how to do so.

Comment: we would actually need some of your HTML too. You should aim for a css only solution. Probably start with removing overflow: hidden;

Comment: may you could post a code snipped?

Comment: @HorstJahns updated!  The form uses the Zend Framework, so the HTML for the individual elements is created through Zend

Comment: Auto generated HTML could be the problem. You should debug in chrome/ff and try to change the css. This is a styling problem! It is really hard to find a solution, if we do not even have the actual html.

Comment: @HorstJahns Well, I've been playing around with dev tools and have seen that changing the height in the div that I refer to in the CSS snippet will do exactly what I want, it's just not dynamic.  So I just need to figure out how to to update the height of that div.  I can post the generated html

Comment: The code in your question doesn't recreate the problem. The div you've shown us does not have a height, and therefore will grow with the content.

Comment: @KevinB the div does not have a height, but it doesn't grow when the fields are dynamically added to the form. It stays the same height and cuts off the overflow.  Removing `overflow: hidden` prevents the overflow from being cut off, but it doesn't change the height of the div

Comment: My point is the problem is somewhere else. You haven't included that somewhere else, so this question is not answerable other than through wild guesses and poor workarounds.

Comment: @KevinB I guess I don't understand how it's somewhere else.  If I modify the CSS on `.wizard .content` it modifies exactly what I need it to.  I just need to modify that when a specific action happens.

Comment: Here's your code (at least, the parts that you have provided) showing that .content inside of .wizard will automatically resize based on the content: https://jsfiddle.net/5z30852w/1/ therefore, the css/js you have provided will not restrict said div from growing with additional content. there must be a parent element that is restricting it somewhere.

Comment: @KevinB Nothing is restricting it. But fields are added to the form while the user is on the page.  So it is not growing when the fields are appended

Comment: Using the dev tools, you should be able to see that the .content div is growing outside of it's parent. or that the inputs are growing outside of the form, or something similar. The inputs are there, you just have to see which element is hiding them.

Comment: @KevinB check out the photos I've added, that show the problem a bit better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105176/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-tibsar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're running into an issue that has been discussed on the jQuery Steps plugin github page: https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/issues/147

basically, since the body of the step content is positioned absolutely with a percent height, it's height is no longer based on the content within it. A few things people used to try to fix this are:

By [waqashsn](https://github.com/waqashsn):

```
.content > .body{
    /*position: absolute*/
    float:left;
    width:95%;
    height:95%;
    padding:2.5%
}
```

Here's another alternative by [AneeshRS](https://github.com/AneeshRS) that instead causes overflowing content to scroll:

```
.wizard.clearfix > .content.clearfix{
    min-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Checkout the link to the issues page for a better explanation of either of these. Note however that any solution that involves removing the absolute positioning will likely cause transitions to no longer work.